# Nested Promise with lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, promise

I'm using Parse.com to store the data of my app and I'm currently stuck with some nested promises. I'm quite new to this concept and I wrote that:

```
this.loadCategories = function() {
      var global = ParseService.toAngularPromise(new Parse.Query(Categories).find());
      global.then(function(categories){
        return categories.forEach(function (category){
          var criteriaPerCategory = ParseService.toAngularPromise(category.relation('relevantCriteria').query().find());
          return criteriaPerCategory.then(function (allCriteriaPerCategory){
            category._criteria = allCriteriaPerCategory;
          });
        });
      });
      return global;
    };
```

It nearly works... All promises are getting executed except the last one: this should be called before the view loads in Angular and it basically works except that the line `category._criteria = allCriteriaPerCategory;` is called after the view has been created and I do not understand why.

I know that this style for writing promises is not very academic but I didn't find any better solution because of this list... I'd very happy to get some insights about my code!

The `ParseService` is only a service which creates Angular Promises from normal JS Promises.

Comment: the `return` from `global.then` is `categories` .... returning to `forEach` does nothing. If you need those all to complete will probably need `$q.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of time I changed strategy and ended up with that:

```
  this.loadCategories2 = function () {

    function loadAllData(category) {
      var relatedCriteria = category.relation('relevantCriteria').query().find().then(function (criteria) {
        category._criteria = criteria;
        return category;
      });
      return $q.when(relatedCriteria);
    }

    return ParseService.toAngularPromise(new Parse.Query(Categories).find()).then(function (categories) {
      return $q.all(categories.map(loadAllData))
    })
  }
```

I'm very interested in comments for that answer but it basically does what I was expecting :)

Comment: I think you should do the `categoryToAdd._criteria = category[1]; return categoryToAdd;` part right in a `then` callback in `loadAllData`. That way you don't need to return `$q.all([$q.when(category), relatedCriteria])`

Comment: But `loadAllData` isn't part of a `then` handler. It's the mapping function to stack the promises.

Comment: @Bergi I did your changes and it still works! I just edited my answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MinusFour Can you explain why it could be a problem? I do not get your point :(

Comment: Good :-) In fact you don't even need the `relatedCriteria` variable and the `$q.when()` call, but can just directly `return category.…().then(…);`

Comment: It isn't a problem. I just got really confused with your last code.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is just launching promises into the wind, there's no chaining being done. You need to stack all these promises and then check when all of them are done. This can be easily done with `map` and `$q.all`. You just need to inject that dependency.

```
this.loadCategories = function() {
  var global = ParseService.toAngularPromise(new Parse.Query(Categories).find());
  return global.then(function(categories){
    return $q.all(categories.map(function (category){
      var criteriaPerCategory = ParseService.toAngularPromise(category.relation('relevantCriteria').query().find());
      return criteriaPerCategory.then(function (allCriteriaPerCategory){
        category._criteria = allCriteriaPerCategory;
        return category;
      });
    }));
  });
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, can you just explain what does the map function does?

Comment: It gets you an array of your returned promises. It literally stacks your promises into a new array. Which is then used by `$q.all` to resolve once every promise has fulfill.

Comment: Hum, I do understand what you did but I still do not have the last line executed (`category._criteria = allCriteriaPerCategory;`) before the view creation (but it works very well after the view creation).

Comment: Is `$q` loaded? Is the view created after `loadCategories` promise settles?

Comment: Yes was loaded, I didn't really understood why it wasn't working but I totally changed my approach and I'll post my answer

Comment: You probably want to `return category` in the innermost callback. The `return global` should be omitted.

Comment: He probably wants to return something in the innermost callback if he's building an array in his other response, but I'm not sure if he wants to return `category` (it is a different one from the other response)

Comment: Well, currently your function returns a promise that resolves with an array of `undefined`s. Don't think that's what OP is looking for…

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
categories.reduce(function (p, category) {
  return p.then(() => ParseService.toAngularPromise(category.relation('relevantCriteria').query().find()));
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function () {
  // do whatever.
});
```